# Request header name different on server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I'm sending an ajax request through jQuery with the headers `{'x-Multiple-Requests': 'true'}`. However, on the server (PHP) I noticed it is received in the `$_SERVER` variable as `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_MULTIPLE_REQUESTS']`. If I call `apache_request_headers()` it is displayed in the array as `['x-Multiple-Requests']`.

As `apache_request_headers()` is not always available on PHP < 5.4 I'm looking for a way to solve this name change elegantly.

Can I restore the name to its original from the `$_SERVER` variable? Or should I change the header name to `X_MULTIPLE_REQUESTS` on the front end so that the `$_SERVER` variable name would not change when it's formatted?

Comment: Why is the name changing a problem?

Comment: It's unexpected. At this time my server side config is different than client side config, which is inconsistent and asking for trouble.

Comment: It shouldn't be unexpected. The `$_SERVER` variable always has uppercase names with underscores. You'll either have to get used to that or use `apache_request_headers`. Do you actually need to target something earlier than 5.4?